# Android studio gradle build compile error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am really newbie on Android and I am facing some problems in Android Studio but I could not find any solution on the net.
If you help I will be appreciated.
Can I find which lines create errors below?

Thanks

Gradle Build:

```
Error:(7, 11) error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(7, 12) error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(1, 1) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(1, 2) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(1, 3) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(7, 11) error: illegal character: '\ufffd'
Error:(7, 12) error: illegal character: '\ufffd'
```

Gradle Console:

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
D:\Projects\ABCApp_v3\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\company\abcapp\BuildConfig.java:7: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
          ï¿½ï¿½R

D:\Projects\ABCApp_v3\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\company\abcapp\BuildConfig.java:7: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
          ï¿½ï¿½R

D:\Projects\ABCApp_v3\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\company\abcapp\BuildConfig.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

D:\Projects\ABCApp_v3\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\company\abcapp\BuildConfig.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

D:\Projects\ABCApp_v3\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\company\abcapp\BuildConfig.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

D:\Projects\ABCApp_v3\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\company\abcapp\BuildConfig.java:7: error: illegal character: '\ufffd'
          ??R

D:\Projects\ABCApp_v3\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\company\abcapp\BuildConfig.java:7: error: illegal character: '\ufffd'
          ??R

5 errors

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Update:
build.gradle file in app folder

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    compileOptions.encoding = "utf-8"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.abcapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

Comment: Are you setting any BuildConfig variables in your gradle script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Looks like a problem related to BOM ([Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark))

**Method 1**

Use an advanced text-editor (for example Notepad++) and set the encoding to "UTF without BOM", for your files.
You can find this option in Notepad++ under `Enconding > Encode in UTF-8 without BOM`

[image]

**Method 2**

Use Android Studio. Changed file Encoding option to UTF-16 and back to UTF-8. Then there should a popup appear, choose the option `Convert`.

[image]